# Selenium IEDriver finds wrong element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

**My html:**

```
<ul class="level1 MenuItemClass static" tabindex="0" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;" role="menubar">
<li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:17" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;">
    <a class="level1 MenuItemClass static" onclick="__doPostBack('mg200$Menu1','Menu1')" href="#" tabindex="-1">Menu1</a>
    <ul id="Menu1:submenu:17" class="level2 MenuItemClass dynamic" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
        <li class="dynamic" role="menuitem" style="position: relative;">
            <a class="level2 MenuItemClass selected dynamic" href="/page1.aspx" tabindex="-1">Submenu1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:22" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;">
    <a class="level1 MenuItemClass static" onclick="__doPostBack('mg200$Menu1','Menu2')" href="#" tabindex="-1">menu2</a>
    <ul id="Menu1:submenu:22" class="level2 MenuItemClass dynamic" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
        <li class="dynamic" role="menuitem" style="position: relative;">
            <a class="level2 MenuItemClass dynamic" href="/page2.aspx" tabindex="-1">Submenu2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**My code:**

```
...
            moveToElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Menu1')]"));
            moveToElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Submenu1')]"));
            clickWhenTheElementIsClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Submenu1')]"), 10);
...
        public void moveToElement(By locator) {
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(locator)).perform();           
        }   

        protected void clickWhenTheElementIsClickable(By locator, long timeout) {
            WebDriverWait wait = (WebDriverWait)new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
            WebElement element = wait.until(
                    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
            element.click();
        }       
...
```

Line:

```
moveToElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Submenu1')]"));
```

works as:

```
moveToElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'menu2')]"));
```

So I am expecting "Submenu1" to be clicked. But the cursor moves to "Menu2" instead.
Using IEDriver 2.38.0
Firefox works fine.
Any ideas? 
Tried clean the project. Didn't help.

Comment: When you get there in your test, are all your menus open (showing their submenus)?

Comment: Yes, 
after "moveToElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Menu1')]"));"
the Submenu1 is shown for a while, 
then the cursor goes to "Menu2"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
There was a strange area conflict in 'Submenu1' and 'Submenu2' elements.
So, I edited my moveToElement() method:

```
public void moveToElement(By locator) {
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(locator), 1, 1).perform();         
}
```

Now it works fine in Firefox and IE.
Hope, it would help smb.